# How to setup Shopper Approved? I suppose to add their code to the check-out page to make their "survey" appear after the check-out process

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout

Magento 1.9.1.0

We purchased the Shopper Approved package which basically asks the customers to leave a reference:

1. The first "quick survey" should appear on the CONFIRMATION page after a customer places an order and if they fill it out - it gets posted to Google, Facebook and who knows where else. If they fill out this initial survey - they will also get the
2. FULL survey by Email a few days later.

What I need to figure out is - **How do I add the code they gave me to the page that comes up for the customer after they placed their order?**

---

**Updated on February 7th, 2019:**

The path that worked for me in the end is:

> public_html/app/design/frontend/smartwave/porto/template/checkout/success.phtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the **PHTML-template**

```
template/checkout/success.phtml
```

**from** the **Magento core theme** folder

```
app/design/frontend/base/default
```

**to** your **own theme** folder

```
app/design/frontend/YOURTHEME/default
```

Comment: And then just paste the code they gave me to the success.phtml file? Any specific place where I need to put that in or anything special to keep in mind when doing this? Thanks! :-)

Comment: Yes paste your code and if your that code want any further configuration like controller or anything then you have to change according @Allysin

Comment: I did that - I placed the code at the end of the "success.phtml" in /home/myaccount/public_html/app/design/frontend/smartwave/default/ but it does not seem to work. When I do CTRL+U to see the code on that page - it does not show the code! Any ideas?

Comment: echo some random stuff in `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/success.phtml`   file, if random stuff is showing in that file then just paste your code below that@Allysin

Comment: That is very smart! ;-) I did put an extra word in and also made one of the words capital (PRINT), then cleared my Cache and re-indexed, placed a test order but the changes did not reflect which must mean that this is NOT the correct path for the file...I am using the Magento PORTO theme on Magento 1.9.1.0. I tried to do a search on Magento Porto and Shopper Approved but I can't find anything at all :-( The /home/myaccount/public_html/app/design/frontend/smartwave/default/success.phtml path seems logical to me but must not be correct...What do you think? :-*

Comment: @ Gopal Patel Shall I modify the success.phtml file in app/design/frontend/base/default you think?

Comment: @Allysin you can but its not good practice. `app/design/frontend/smartwave/default/template/checkout/success.p‌​html` Have you tried in this file?

Comment: I am still struggling with this. It turns out I don't have a success.phtml in my  app/design/frontend/base/default  Any ideas? Thank you! :-*